# Pandoc powerpoint with template : title slide is blank

Tags: templates, markdown, powerpoint, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to write a slideshow as Markdown and then export it as Powerpoint file with a `.potx` template, through the `--reference-doc` as mentionned in [Pandoc's documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL%202.html).

Everything is working fine, except that the title slide is blank in the result. It correclty uses the "Title Slide" master slide from the template, but the title, presenter name and dates, which are specified in the pandoc metadata are not inserted.

If I remove the master slide from my template, the data is rendered correctly but using the "Standard Slide" master slide.

Any clue about this ?

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour, both using a `.potx` template and a `.pptx` file as the `--reference-doc`. However, the "Standard Slice" workaround doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the only solution that worked for me is a workaround. In my case, generating a `.pptx`-File from my template always resultet in a corrupt file, which had to be "Repaired" upon opening with PowerPoint.

So I started with pandoc's default reference doc:

```
pandoc -o ref.pptx --print-default-data-file reference.pptx
```

Then I mangled `ref.pptx`, which already contained everything needed for workable documents, into the template I actually wanted to use.

I had no issues since, and the title slide is displayed as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify my metadata using this specific format:

```
title: Title
author: John Doe
```

Originally I had this, which did not work:

```
title:
- Title
author:
- John Doe
```

In spite of this, both worked for generating pdf slideshows using `beamer`.